# Windows 10: set default folder for Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

In Windows 10, how do I set the default folder for Windows Explorer shortcut?
In regedit, the

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

doesn't have a LaunchTo keyword to edit.

Do I create this folder and set the DWORD to the location that I want to use as the default?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcut to open Explorer anywhere, e.g. create a shortcut and set the location to

> C:\Windows\explorer.exe "c:\Program Files"

Then right-click on the shortcut, select *Properties* and set a *shortcut key* combination.

This allows you to have not just one, but a few default locations that open with just a few keystrokes.

The trouble with setting the Registry default is that it can change as you open an Explorer instance, navigate in it, and then close it.